# How to create a quiz that has different questions on different pages?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a small quiz at the end of each of page. I have a quiz written on JavaScript but I want different questions to appear in different pages. In a few words, I want the const myQuestions to change if i am on different pages. How can I achieve this?

I already tried with if statements but I couldn't achieve what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the JS code of the quiz

```
(function() {

  const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "question 1?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "question 2?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "question 3?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
        d: "four"
      },
      correctAnswer: "d"
    }
  ];



  function buildQuiz() {
    // we'll need a place to store the HTML output
    const output = [];

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // we'll want to store the list of answer choices
      const answers = [];

      // and for each available answer...
      for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
        // ...add an HTML radio button
        answers.push(
          `<label>
             <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
           </label>`
        );
      }

      // add this question and its answers to the output
      output.push(
        `<div class="slide">
           <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
           <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
         </div>`
      );
    });

    // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
  }

  function showResults() {
    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll(".answers");

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

      // if answer is correct
      if (userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
        // add to the number of correct answers
        numCorrect++;

        // color the answers green
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "lightgreen";
      } else {
        // if answer is wrong or blank
        // color the answers red
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = "red";
      }
    });

    // show number of correct answers out of total
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
  }

  function showSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active-slide");
    slides[n].classList.add("active-slide");
    currentSlide = n;

    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      previousButton.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      previousButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

    if (currentSlide === slides.length - 1) {
      nextButton.style.display = "none";
      submitButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      nextButton.style.display = "inline-block";
      submitButton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function showNextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById("results");
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  // display quiz right away
  buildQuiz();

  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  showSlide(0);

  // on submit, show results
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
})();
```

Comment: JavaScript, when used on a web page, is run for that page only. It probably doesn't make a lot of sense to adapt this to multiple physical pages. You can simulate multiple pages as a number of SPA (single page application) frameworks do using HTML5's history API, or by hiding/showing elements on the page as questions are answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mileage may vary, depends on what you want to do. With just javascript, you could pass `windows.location.pathname` to your function each time it's called and choose the appropriate object of questions related to the path you need.

```
if (windows.location.pathname).includes('page1') {
  let currentQuestion = myQuestions[0]
} 
//...rest of the logic
```

Comment: This would require having the same code on each page, of course.

Comment: Yep. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Thanks, I have a question about the includes(). What should I pass in there that will distunish it for each page? Should i just pass in the name of the page? Also, can you give me an example on how to initialise myQuestions[0] with all the questions and answers? Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: The includes would just contain whatever your page names are. `window.location.pathname` going to pull back whatever is after your domain, so `localhost:8080/page/1` becomes `page/1`. So however you're distinguishing each page, you'll want that inside includes

Comment: Thanks! how can I initialise myQuestions[0] with all this information though? const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "question 1?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "question 2?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "question 3?",
      answers: {
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three"
        d: "four"
      },
      correctAnswer: "d"
    }
  ];

Comment: Can you put some of your code in a JSFiddle? There's a good deal of HTML you're working with using this logic. Easier to show than to explain only in words.